# Balancing out a good souffle and burnt cheese on top

Tags: souffle

I have a  souffle egg recipe that calls for grated Parmesan cheese on the top. I want to also have the cheese slightly burnt without having the souffle collapse. Is there a way to do this? My ideas: If I use the upper part of the oven, wouldn't that overheat the souffle? Or Should I slowly bake the souffle at a low temperature and then for 60 seconds or so use the upper part of the oven. I don't have a blowtorch, if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is pre-cooking the Parmesan. Basically, make crisps, like this:

[image: 1]

But perhaps a bit darker. Allow them to cool, then crush them or even give them a quick whirr in the food processor. Top your souffle with the cooked cheese crumble instead of uncooked Parmesan.

BTW, that picture is from [Giada De Laurentiis'](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/giada-de-laurentiis/parmesan-crisps-recipe.html) recipe.